# Why is the verb for "pretexts ... and necessity ... was exposed" used in the singular in this quotation?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, literature

In the following context, a quote from *The Three Musketeers*, shouldn’t it be ***were*** exposed?

> The pretexts about the cold and the necessity for the cloak was exposed.

Or  is *was* here referring just to *the necessary* but not including *pretexts*?

Comment: It's possible, but without knowing more of the context we can't be sure. In any case, your book must be a translation from the French.

Comment: The quote I posted is a complete sentence not a part of one. Yes, from the original French.

Comment: Yes, but what is the context of the sentence? What are 'the pretexts about the cold'?

Comment: 'Were' seems to be correct, unless there is a reason to justify the use of 'was'.

Comment: The text does not appear in the Project Gutenberg English version; the OP should cite the source, with a link.

Comment: Well presumably the idea is that it was very cold so whoever it was had to wear a cloak - that sounds very much like one pretext to me, so I think *the pretext... was...* is at least as likely.

Comment: @JD2000: actually, the "cold" is a translation of *rhume*, which is the head type of cold and not the temperature type of cold.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks - still sounds like one pretext to me but then I don't have the book (whether a Google books link opens seems to depend on where you are).

Comment: @JD2000: Indeed, there is only one pretext. Porthos has to wear his cloak to avoid revealing how poor he is, so he pretends to have a cold. But in the original English translation (see my answer below), it's *were* because two things are exposed: the pretext about the cold and the necessity for the cloak. Of course, these are essentially the same thing. The French is worded quite differently.

Comment: @PeterShor OK - looks to me as though a subsequent editor may have decided it was better in the singular and changed both subject and verb on autopilot... though that leaves the mystery of the missing *thus* unsolved. Anyway, I think the answer to the OP is that *was* is fine but it should be *pretext*.

Comment: Possibly: "Alas, like most things in this world which have nothing in their favor but appearances, the baldric was glittering with gold in the front, but was nothing but simple buff behind. Vainglorious as he was, Porthos could not afford to have a baldric wholly of gold, but had at least half. **One could comprehend the necessity of the cold and the urgency of the cloak.**" https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1257/1257-h/1257-h.htm Perhaps the OP's version is poorly translated.

Comment: @CJ Dennis: I wouldn't say the OP's version is a poor translation, although you could call it a looser translation; literal translations are never a good idea. The literal translation would be "Since then, one comprehended the necessity of the cold and the urgency of the cloak," which sounds horrible.

Comment: @PeterShor If I have found the correct passage, what exactly does "The pretexts about the cold" mean?

Comment: @CJDennnis: It means that Porthos pretended to have a cold so that he would have an excuse to wear his cloak, so that nobody would see that his baldric didn't have any gold in the back. As the OP says, it should either be *pretext ... was* or *pretexts ... were*.

Comment: @PeterShor That quote is really hard to understand out of context. I've found the relevant passages on Gutenberg. "This Musketeer had just come off guard, complained of having a cold, and coughed from time to time affectedly. It was for this reason, as he said to those around him, that he had put on his cloak; and while he spoke with a lofty air and twisted his mustache disdainfully, all admired his embroidered baldric, and d’Artagnan more than anyone." Porthos is introduced in chapter 2 with a cold (and a baldric), and the cold isn't mentioned again until this quote in chapter 4.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very mangled version of the original (which is grammatical).

The original (found in [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=vsJHnjfYcu0C&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=%22the+pretext%22+%22about+the+cold%22+necessity&source=bl&ots=8mdbqRASQl&sig=ACfU3U1S3O3cDXzX8T549lApp3vGpyXNMw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwio1uWR6J3nAhUp11kKHWm3BGQQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20pretext%22%20%22about%20the%20cold%22%20necessity&f=false)) is:

> The **pretext** about the cold and the necessity for the cloak **were thus** exposed.

It seems difficult to believe that it is merely an independent translation of the French; 
the original is:

> on comprenait dès lors la nécessité du rhume et l'urgence du manteau,

of which a relatively literal translation would be

> at that point, he understood the need for the cold and the urgency of the cloak.

It is hard to imagine how an independent translation would have chanced to be so similar.

Comment: Many thanks, Peter.

Comment: How did you find the full sentence in the book? I can only see the table of contents.

Comment: @CJDennis: Google books doesn't always give the same view for different regions.